# PHP syntax equivalent to SQL %

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a folder `unit_images` that is full of images with random names except they have a prefix that corresponds to a `PRIMARY KEY` in a db table.

`1_4534534fw4.jpg`

`2_43534tw4t45.png`

You get my point. I am using YoxView to view images and am doing something like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE unit = ".$_GET['id']."";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo '<div class="yoxview">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<img src="unit_images/01.jpg" alt="First" title="First image" />
    <img src="unit_images/02.jpg" alt="Second" title="Second image" />'
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

I want to list the images from my folder `unit_images` WHERE the unit is the one currently being shown.I just do not know how to tell PHP the filename. I want  to do something similar to a `1_%` in SQL. Does that make sense? Since I do not know what the rest of the filename looks like I just need to tell php it doesn't matter.

Comment: So I guess you haven't stored the string of the file after the `id` part in your database, right?

Comment: Your `$query` is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). For your own safety, you'll want to fix that before you take this code live.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent to SQL's `%` wildcard that works for files is the shell's `*` wildcard, which is available in php through [the `glob()` function](http://php.net/glob). You can iterate through its results as follows:

```
foreach (glob("unit_images/1_*.jpg") as $filename) {
  echo '<img src="unit_images/' . htmlspecialchars(basename($filename)) 
     . '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a list of items in a directory with a certain prefix.
Step 1 (use `sandir()` to determine the items in the directory):

```
$files = scandir('unit_images');
```

Step 2 (eliminate the unwanted image names):

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); i++)
{
    $file = $files[i];
    $prefix = explode("_", $file)[0];
    if ($prefix != $_GET['id'])
    {
        unset($files[i]);
    }
}
```

`$files` is now an array of only the file names prefixed with `$_GET['id]`

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to store the whole name of the file in a column so that you can reference it directly instead of having to search in the file system for a matching name.

Having said that, you can search for a file using the [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) PHP function.

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
glob("unit_images/<YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY>_*.{png,jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
```